# Template types not working in Scala?

Tags: scala, templates, types, sbt, scala-2.10

[Here are the errors](http://pastebin.com/VaWwzx8V) I received when running `sbt run` on this listing [3.5] from `[1]`:

```scala
import util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

trait ArithParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
    type T
    def expr: Parser[T] = chainl1(term,   "+" ^^^ Add |  "-" ^^^ Sub)
    def term            = chainl1(factor, "*" ^^^ Mul |  "/" ^^^ Div)
    def factor          = floatingPointNumber  ^^ Num | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"

    def Add = (T,T)  => T
    def Sub = (T,T)  => T
    def Mul = (T,T)  => T
    def Div = (T,T)  => T
    def Num = String => T
}

trait DirectEvaluation {
    type T = Double
    val Add = (_: Double) + (_:Double)
    val Sub = (_: Double) - (_:Double)
    val Mul = (_: Double) * (_:Double)
    val Div = (_: Double) / (_:Double)
    val Num = (_: String).toDouble
}

trait ASTBuilding {
    type T = Expr
    sealed abstract class Expr

    case class Add(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Sub(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Mul(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Div(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
    case class Num(e: String) extends Expr
}

object Interpreter extends ArithParser with DirectEvaluation
object Compiler extends ArithParser with ASTBuilding

object Main extends ArithParser {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val defArgs = if (args.isEmpty) Array("10.5 - 4*2") else args
        val parser: ArithParser = if(defArgs.head === "eval") {
                println("Interpreter!"); Interpreter
            } else {
                println("Compiler!"); Compiler
            }
        defArgs.tail foreach {arg =>
            println("Input: " + arg)
            println("Output: " + parseAll(parser.expr, arg))
        }
    }
}
```

`[1]` [E. Labun, “Combinator Parsing in Scala,” Technische Hochschule Mittelhessen, 2012.](http://labun.com/fh/ma.pdf)

How do I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1):

The `(T,T) => T` is a type annotation, so you have to replace the `=` with a `:`.

```
def Add: (T,T) => T
```

That is also exactly how it is in the thesis you refer to.

The `===` also does not exist in the listing, it's just a `==`.

And you have to call `parseAll` on the parser:

```
parser.parseAll(...)
```

It seems to me that you are missing the basics of scala programming, otherwise you could have easily fixed those errors yourself. My advice is, read a good scala book to get a basic understanding of the language before you start with advanced topics.

Comment: Admittedly I did try copy and pasting the code directly at one point in my debugging, which didn't fix the issue. Anyway, what you pointed out are silly mistakes, guess 3 days without sleep increases the frequency of such >.<. Cheers.